# bal is not a fuction (DISCORD.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, command, discord.js, args

I have been trying to implement complex code on command handlers but then I get an error saying the following:

```
TypeError: bal is not a function
at Object.execute (C:\Users\tom\Documents\TJ\bot\commands\uwu uwubon.js:17:7)
at Client.client.on.message (C:\Users\tom\Documents\TJ\bot\index.js:153:11)
at Client.emit (events.js:198:13)
at MessageCreateHandler.handle (C:\Users\tom\Documents\TJ\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\MessageCreate.js:9:34)
at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (C:\Users\tom\Documents\TJ\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:105:65)
at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (C:\Users\tom\Documents\TJ\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (C:\Users\tom\Documents\TJ\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\tom\Documents\TJ\bot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
at WebSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)
at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\tom\Documents\TJ\bot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:789:20)
```

I honestly don't know much about javascript so it is very difficult for me to troubleshoot the problem alone. I have tried various ways in trying to fix the problem from experimenting between var, let, and const, to completely changing the composition of the code but to no avail.

If you are wondering how my code looks like, here it is:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')

module.exports = {
  name: 'uwubon',
  colldown: 3,
  guildOnly: false,
  aliases: [],
  rank: 1,
  description: '',
  execute(message, args) {
    var bal = require('../db/uwus.json')
    let uwuval = 1000
    let menuser = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.member.get(args[0]));
    let curuwu = bal[message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.member.get(args[0])).uwus]

    if (message.author.id == 335562919364263938) {
      bal(menuser).uwus = curuwu + uwuval
    } else return message.reply('You are not eligible for that command!')

  },
};
```

PS: For those who are wondering, yes, I did repost this because I accidentally used a different version of the command code.

Comment: `var bal = require('../db/uwus.json')` ... well, `bal` is definitely not a function, no more can be said ... looks like you meant to type `bal[menuser].uwus = curuwu + uwuval`

Comment: You appear to be setting `bal` to the a json file, but then using it as a function.

Comment: @Gavin the file is a .js file as seen here https://imgur.com/a/HIUly6o

Comment: @JaromandaX I need a way to define bal because this is in a separate js file from my main js file.

Comment: you have defined bal ... it's `var bal = require('../db/uwus.json')` ... but it still looks like you meant to type `bal[menuser].uwus = curuwu + uwuval` instead, since you can't assign a value to the result of a function, as that makes no sense - did you even try that?

Comment: @JaromandaX Ohhh now I get it. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

bal isn't a function so you shouldn't use `()`. Its an object seeing as you're trying to extract data from a json file. In order to access the data of an object you would need to replace the `()` with `[]`. So `bal(menuser)` on the 17th line would be `bal[menuser]`.

Comment: tried this but then got another error which can be seen [here](https://pastebin.com/zPwKMKjq)